# Is there any way to get my Minecraft world back?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I recently removed my Xbox account from my Xbox and when I added it back, my Minecraft worlds from the last couple months were deleted.

I looked back at what it said when I deleted my account, and it said that files that haven't been uploaded yet will be deleted. I tried clearing my cache to get those to re-sync with the game - nothing. Deleted and reinstalled the game - nothing. Uninstalled the beta and redownloaded - nothing. Is it gone for good or do I have hope?

Comment: That depends. Are you willing to pay a data recovery firm a completely unreasonable amount of money in exchange for them to (probably) tell you "Nope, sorry, you're out of luck"?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, if you have no export/backup uploaded to a cloud service you're out of luck! There is no way to recover deleted files on an Xbox.